# How do I properly request information from this API?

Tags: json, python-3.x, api

Like the title says, I'm having problems accessing information from an API. This is the message I receive when running the function:

```
{'message': 'no Route matched with those values'}
```

This is the full code: API key blocked out just because.

```
import tkinter as tk
import requests

# API Key : xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx
# Player Stats Request: https://api.fortnitetracker.com/v1/profile/{platform}/{epic-nickname}


squad = {}
platforms = ['xb1', 'psn', 'pc']


def get_player(player):
    headers = {'TRN-Api-Key': 'xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx'}
    url = 'https://api.fortnitetracker.com/v1/profile'
    params = {'platform': 'pc', 'epic-nickname': player}
    response = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
    print(response.json())


# setting up the screen
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("800x600")
root.maxsize(800, 600)
root.title("Fortnite Squad Leaderboard")
root.iconphoto(True, tk.PhotoImage(file="bigpot.png"))

# background image
background_img = tk.PhotoImage(file='fortnitebg.png')
background_label = tk.Label(root, image=background_img)
background_label.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

top_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="lightblue")
top_frame.place(relx=0, rely=0, relwidth=0.4, relheight=0.06)

player_search_button = tk.Button(top_frame, text="Player Search", command=lambda: 
get_player(player_search.get()))
player_search_button.place(relx=0.7, rely=0.2, relwidth=0.28, relheight=0.6)

player_search = tk.Entry(top_frame)
player_search.place(relx=0.05, rely=0.2, relwidth=0.63, relheight=0.6)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Probably you should incorporate `platform` and `epic-nickname` values into the `url` itself instead of submitting them as `params`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL `https://api.fortnitetracker.com/v1/profile/{platform}/{epic-nickname}` accepts the params `platform` and `epic-nickname` as **URL Params** and not **Query Params**

Query params are those params you add at the end of the URL like `?k=v&k1=v1` and URL params are part of the URL.

So the URL should look like

```
https://api.fortnitetracker.com/v1/profile/pc/player
```

So instead of doing

```
url = 'https://api.fortnitetracker.com/v1/profile'
params = {'platform': 'pc', 'epic-nickname': player}
response = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
```

You should do like

```
url = f'https://api.fortnitetracker.com/v1/profile/pc/{player}'
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

This must work for you.

Comment: Thanks Kris this worked ! You're awesome.   Would you mind explaining what that f does before the URL? I understand its allowing the player variable to be called into the url but I've never seen this before. I only started programming like a week ago.

Comment: Its an alternative to .format() function. You can read about it here https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings